# How to get the shortest distance with one source and two destination using Djikstras algo?

Tags: python, graph, shortest-path

I used an already available code which returns the shortest distance between a source and destination tried updating the code for getting shortest path between a source and two destinations based on which I can compare the two paths. But it seems to not work. I'll appreciate it if any help can be provided.

Below is the code:

```
def dijkstra(graph,start,goal):
    minimumContainmentZones = {}
    predecessor = {}
    unseenNodes = graph
    infinity = 9999999
    path = []
    for node in unseenNodes:
        minimumContainmentZones[node] = infinity
    minimumContainmentZones[start] = 0
 
    while unseenNodes:
        minNode = None
        for node in unseenNodes:
            if minNode is None:
                minNode = node
            elif minimumContainmentZones[node] < minimumContainmentZones[minNode]:
                minNode = node
 
        for childNode, weight in graph[minNode].items():
            if weight + minimumContainmentZones[minNode] < minimumContainmentZones[childNode]:
                minimumContainmentZones[childNode] = weight + minimumContainmentZones[minNode]
                predecessor[childNode] = minNode
        unseenNodes.pop(minNode)
 
    currentNode = goal
    while currentNode != start:
        try:
            path.insert(0,currentNode)
            currentNode = predecessor[currentNode]
        except KeyError:
            print('Path not reachable')
            break
    path.insert(0,start)
    if minimumContainmentZones[goal] != infinity:
        return(goal,minimumContainmentZones[goal],str(path))
    
 
 
if __name__=="__main__":
    graph = {'a':{'b':5,'c':3,'d':2},'b':{'a':3,'e':11,'f':12},'c':{'a':5,'f':7},'d':{'a':2,'f':8,'g':5},'e':{'b':11,'f':3,'h':3},'f':{'b':12,'c':7,'d':8,'e':3,'g':4,'h':7,'i':5,'k':4},'g':{'d':5,'f':4,'k':5},'h':{'e':3,'f':7,'j':2},'i':{'f':5,'j':3} ,  'j':{'h':2,'i':3,'k':6}  ,'k':{'g':5,'f':4,'j':6} }  
    a,b,c=dijkstra(graph, 'a', 'h')
    d,e,f=dijkstra(graph, 'a', 'j')
    print(a,b,c)
    print(d,e,f)
```

Gives me the error:

```
Path not reachable
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-bc57edb9feb6> in <module>
     40     graph = {'a':{'b':5,'c':3,'d':2},'b':{'a':3,'e':11,'f':12},'c':{'a':5,'f':7},'d':{'a':2,'f':8,'g':5},'e':{'b':11,'f':3,'h':3},'f':{'b':12,'c':7,'d':8,'e':3,'g':4,'h':7,'i':5,'k':4},'g':{'d':5,'f':4,'k':5},'h':{'e':3,'f':7,'j':2},'i':{'f':5,'j':3} ,  'j':{'h':2,'i':3,'k':6}  ,'k':{'g':5,'f':4,'j':6}      }
     41     a,b,c=dijkstra(graph, 'a', 'h')
---> 42     d,e,f=dijkstra(graph, 'a', 'j')
     43     print(a,b,c)
     44     print(d,e,f)

<ipython-input-93-bc57edb9feb6> in dijkstra(graph, start, goal)
     32             break
     33     path.insert(0,start)
---> 34     if minimumContainmentZones[goal] != infinity:
     35         return(goal,minimumContainmentZones[goal],str(path))
     36 

KeyError: 'j'
```

Comment: In the future, it’s a good idea to comment your code.

Comment: Hi, was your question answered? If so, could you please accept and upvote the answer? If not, what can be clarified?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first time you call the function, you’re modifying your graph by deleting nodes. Then, the second time you call it, the intended nodes aren’t there anymore! The danger came from using `unseenNodes.pop()`.

As a reminder, assignment in Python is done by reference, so the line

```
unseenNodes = graph
```

creates another reference to the same graph, rather than a copy of the graph.

---

Here’s one way to fix it: actually making a copy.

At the top your script, use this line:

```
from copy import deepcopy
```

Now, where you said `unseenNodes = graph`, change that to:

```
unseenNodes = deepcopy(graph)
```

The benefit here is that you can modify the new object all you want, without affecting the outer scope’s graph. It’ll then be the same graph both times you call your function on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.This resolved the issue. New to coding :)   Long way to go

Comment: Glad to hear it! If this helped, could you please accept this answer, using the green check mark beside it? And consider upvoting the answer also.